# logging into asp site with python

Tags: asp.net, python

I'm trying to log into https://www.surveymonkey.com/MyAccount_Login.aspx using Python and I'm getting an error back. This is the code I'm using to log in:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
username = '<my user name>'
password = '<my password>'
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data=urllib.urlencode({'wc_Login1$txtUsername':username, 'wc_Login1$txtPassword':password})
opener.open('https://www.surveymonkey.com/MyAccount_Login.aspx', login_data)
```

At this point, I'm getting the following back:

```
<addinfourl at 43343112L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x00000000028A4ED0>>
```

I believe I identified the username and password fields correctly as wc_Login1$txtUsername and wc_Login1$txtPassword using Opera's Dragonfly.

If I add the following to see if I've logged in correctly:

```
resp=opener.open('http://www.surveymonkey.com/MySurveys.aspx')
print resp.read()
```

It appears that I'm still stuck on the login page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>SurveyMonkey - Log in</title>
```

Any thoughts? I've read that logging into asp pages is a pain using python, but this one kinda looked straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is close to a year later and doesn't really address your question. For me, your code works fine but doesn't log into the website. I found a workaround for the log in issue. Instead of trying to log in, I stole the cookie from my browser and set it manually.

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

#Cookie specific information
session = 'cookie_value'
log = cookielib.Cookie(0, 'cookie_name', session, None, False,
                       'domain_name', False, False,
                       'path_name', True, False, None, True, None, None,
                       {'HttpOnly': None}, False)

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
cj.set_cookie(log)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

resp = opener.open('website')
output = open('output.htm', 'w')
output.write(resp.read())
output.close()
```

I don't know much about it, but you may need to reset the cookie value per day or something like that.